# Nesting of Maps in java in which value of map is agin another map

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a map in which key is list of values and matched to one value as shown below basically i want to create a map in which value will again will be of type map

```
 key           value
Deaswe        DealDate
TradeRe       TradeRef
Daelet        DealDate
TF            TradeRef
```

below is the code to achieve that in finally in which dataMap we finally store the elements as shown below

```
Map<String, List<String>> dataMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        dataMap.put ("TradeRef", Arrays.asList("TradeRe","TF"));
        dataMap.put ("DealDate", Arrays.asList( "Daelet", "Deaswe"));


        Map<String, String> itemMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); //New map for item->key mapping
        for(String key: dataMap.keySet()) //Get all keys and iterate through
            for(String item: dataMap.get(key)) //For each item in your value list
                itemMap.put(item, key); //Create new mapping item->key
```

now the above map is working fine but i have to modify this design since i want an another map in which there will be key and its value will be of above type map so it would be like

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>>
```

in other words the above dataMap would be the value type for Map

so the structure would be like

```
key           Value 

B4 ----->    dataMap          

B5  ---->    dataMap
```

and dataMap has its own keys and value 
so it would be like

```
   B4  -->    Deaswe   --> DealDate
    B4 --->    Daelet   --> DealDate
    B5  --->   TradeRe  --> TradeRef
    B5  --->   TF    -->  TradeRef
```

folks please advise how we can create this data structure in which there will be a map of which value type will again be of type map and how do we insert and iterate over it folks please advise
On this

Comment: Why don't you create an object rather than a map of maps? You will have something like `Map<String, Store> map = ...` and add proper instances of `Store` in the map, and this `Store` may contain a `List`, `Map` or any other collection that will contain proper data and provide a method to look up for this data.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza stiil not able to grasp completely please can you please show us Thanks in advance it will be gret if you could please post the code that will help to understand clearly

Comment: Do you want the elements of the new map to be `Map<String, String>` or `Map<String, List<String>>`?

Comment: @patricia it should be Do you want the elements of the new map to be `Map<String, String>`

Answer (score 0):

(Arguably, this should be a comment but it won't fit.)

If a data structure's requirements map really closely to a straightforward use of a standard API class, I use that directly. If things get anywhere near as complicated as your situation, I follow a different strategy:

1. Decide exactly what forms of insertion, iteration, and access you need from the data structure. Which operations are frequent enough to be potential performance issues?
2. Specify that as an interface, and write the corresponding unit tests.
3. Implement the interface, usually using combinations of API classes.

This has several advantages. Complicated combinations of API classes have a lot of functionality, most of which you don't need to specify or test. The complications of iterating over some combination of classes are hidden from most of the code, and tested separately. If you need to change the implementation because of a performance bottleneck or change in requirements, it can be done within the implementation of one class.

I suggest adding to the question the external, black-box requirements, rather than a specific implementation in terms of maps.

Comment: Thanks can you please advise can I create custom data structure then which would be best custom data structure Aldo please can you please show me in which custom data structure it will fit

Comment: The key to selecting the best custom data structure is a clear and complete understanding of the requirements. See step 1 above. I'm afraid I don't have that understanding from the question as it is now.

Comment: Can you please advise understanding is missing

Comment: I want B1 and B2 to have a map types values

Comment: I want to achieve only this format B4 --> Deaswe --> DealDate B4 ---> Daelet --> DealDate B5 ---> TradeRe --> TradeRef B5 ---> TF --> TradeRef

Comment: It would be really grateful if you can please post some code of custom data structure in which this is achieved

Comment: @gfhtghghg Please show your gratitude by doing step 1, putting the information in the question. You only tell me parts of a potential implementation, which may or may not be the best one, not the functionality you need.